# FFMPEG-How can i mix mutilple audio streams with a video having embedded audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

How can i mix mutilple audio streams with a video having embedded audio?
Eg i am having video.mp4 which has embedded audio stream. I want to mix one or more audio streams with it,keeping the orignal embedded audio stream.
How can i do it? Thanks.

Comment: By mix, do you mean add the other audio streams and keep them distinct, or combine new audio data with the existing one to create a mixdown?

Comment: Hi. i meant the later. Combine new audio data with the existing one. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that ffmpeg command-line questions are off topic here and should be posted on [SU]. Voted to migrate the question. (Please don't cross-post, it can be moved there automatically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic template is

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1][2]amix=3[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy out.mp4
```